# htaaccess file redirect for unparallel directories

Tags: .htaccess, architecture, seo

I need to add a rule to my .htaccess file to do this:

Go from the old domain which was this:
http://www.hikingsanfrancisco.com/outdoors/trees/tanoak.php

To a new domain which will be this:
http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trees/129/Tanoak

I have added a rule like this:
RewriteRule http://www.hikingsanfrancisco.com/outdoors/trees/tanoak.php http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/trees/129/Tanoak

But it doesn't work :(

Any idea on how to accomplish what I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who can' get a similar thing to work, try something like this:

RewriteRule ^outdoors/swift_bird.php http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/birds/bird.php?bird_id=1 [R,L]

I know the paths are of different items than the question.  But it doesn't matter.  The difference seemed to be putting the [R,L] at the end of the line.  It was a suggestion from elsewhere, so I am not sure what it does exactly, but it made the redirect work :)